# 401 when calling Web Service only on particular machines

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, restsharp, ntlm, http-status-code-401

We have developed a WPF Application with C# and are using RestSharp to communicate with a simple Web Service like this:

```
Client = new RestClient(serviceUri.AbsoluteUri);
Client.Authenticator = new NtlmAuthenticator(SvcUserName, SvcPassword.GetString());
```

It all worked great until we received calls that on some machines (most work) the app can't connect to the service.
A direct call to the service method with fiddler worked. Then we extracted a small .net console app and tried the service call with RestSharp and directly with a HttpWebRequest and it failed again with 401.
Now we enabled System.Net tracing and noticed something. After the first 401, which is normal,the faulty machine produces this log:

> System.Net Information: 0 : [4480] Connection#3741682 - Received headers
>   {
>   Connection: Keep-Alive
>   Content-Length: 1293
>   Content-Type: text/html
>   Date: Mon, 10 Aug 2015 12:37:49 GMT
>   Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
>   WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate,NTLM
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>   }.
>   System.Net Information: 0 : [4480] ConnectStream#39451090::ConnectStream(Buffered 1293 bytes.)
>   System.Net Information: 0 : [4480] Associating HttpWebRequest#2383799 with ConnectStream#39451090
>   System.Net Information: 0 : [4480] Associating HttpWebRequest#2383799 with HttpWebResponse#19515494
>   System.Net Information: 0 : [4480] Enumerating security packages:
>   System.Net Information: 0 : [4480]     Negotiate
>   System.Net Information: 0 : [4480]     NegoExtender
>   System.Net Information: 0 : [4480]     Kerberos
>   System.Net Information: 0 : [4480]     NTLM
>   System.Net Information: 0 : [4480]     Schannel
>   System.Net Information: 0 : [4480]     Microsoft Unified Security Protocol Provider
>   System.Net Information: 0 : [4480]     WDigest
>   System.Net Information: 0 : [4480]     TSSSP
>   System.Net Information: 0 : [4480]     pku2u
>   System.Net Information: 0 : [4480]     CREDSSP
>
> System.Net Information: 0 : [4480] AcquireCredentialsHandle(package  =
>   **NTLM, intent   = Outbound, authdata =**
>   **(string.empty)\corp\svc_account)**
>
> System.Net Information: 0 : [4480]
>   InitializeSecurityContext(credential =
>   System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY, context = (null), targetName =
>   HTTP/mysvc.mycorp.com, inFlags = Delegate, MutualAuth,
>   Connection) System.Net Information: 0 : [4480]
>   InitializeSecurityContext(In-Buffers count=1, Out-Buffer length=40,
>   returned code=ContinueNeeded).

A working machine produces this output:

> System.Net Information: 0 : [3432] Connection#57733168 - Empfangene Statusleiste: Version = 1.1, StatusCode = 401, StatusDescription = Unauthorized.
>   System.Net Information: 0 : [3432] Connection#57733168 - Header
>   {
>   Content-Type: text/html
>   Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
>   WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate,NTLM
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>   Date: Mon, 10 Aug 2015 15:15:11 GMT
>   Content-Length: 1293
>   } wurden empfangen.
>   System.Net Information: 0 : [3432] ConnectStream#35016340::ConnectStream(Es wurden 1293 Bytes gepuffert.)
>   System.Net Information: 0 : [3432] Associating HttpWebRequest#64062224 with ConnectStream#35016340
>   System.Net Information: 0 : [3432] Associating HttpWebRequest#64062224 with HttpWebResponse#64254500
>   System.Net Information: 0 : [3432] Sicherheitspakete werden enumeriert:
>   System.Net Information: 0 : [3432]     Negotiate
>   System.Net Information: 0 : [3432]     NegoExtender
>   System.Net Information: 0 : [3432]     Kerberos
>   System.Net Information: 0 : [3432]     NTLM
>   System.Net Information: 0 : [3432]     Schannel
>   System.Net Information: 0 : [3432]     Microsoft Unified Security Protocol Provider
>   System.Net Information: 0 : [3432]     WDigest
>   System.Net Information: 0 : [3432]     TSSSP
>   System.Net Information: 0 : [3432]     pku2u
>   System.Net Information: 0 : [3432]     CREDSSP
>
> System.Net Information: 0 : [3432] **AcquireCredentialsHandle(package  =**
>   **Negotiate, intent   = Outbound, authdata =**
>   **System.Net.SafeSspiAuthDataHandle)** System.Net Information: 0 : [3432]
>   InitializeSecurityContext(credential =
>   System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY, context = (null), targetName =
>   HTTP/mysvc.mycorp.com, inFlags = Delegate, MutualAuth, Connection)
>
> System.Net Information: 0 : [3432] InitializeSecurityContext(Anzahl
>   von In-Buffers = 1, Länge von Out-Buffer = 40, zurückgegebener Code =
>   ContinueNeeded).

I wonder if some configuration on the faulty machine would cause this. At the moment I am not sure where to look next.

Update:
Here is the Code of our simple test tool:

```
RestClient Client = new RestClient("https://mysvc.mycorp.com/service.svc");
        Client.Authenticator = new NtlmAuthenticator("corp\\svc_account", "mypassword");
        var request = new RestRequest("api/Method", Method.POST);
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        request.AddBody(new { Device_Key = "somestring" });
        request.Timeout = 200000;


        RestResponse response = (RestResponse)Client.Execute(request);
```

Update 2:
We have now confirmed that this Problem only occurs on newly installed win 7 machines that have an updated corporate Image. Almost Looks like some update in the last 2 months is screwing with us.

Comment: Could you post the MCVE console application you created?

Comment: here you go, I added the code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is crazy: Turns out, as soon as I installed .net 4.5 on the Windows 7 machine, the WebRequest worked! We believe that the culprit was a missing patch of the .NET 4.0 Framework that is deployed to all client machines.
So, patch your machines :)